# Create a small control panel on screen for pyautogui monitoring and control purposes

Tags: python, debugging, controls, monitoring, pyautogui

How do I display a small control panel screen that can control and monitoring `pyautogui` process? I expect there is a pinned window that for monitoring purpose such as displaying current log.txt that has been generated by `logging` and controlling purpose such as pause and resume button? Actually these are inteded for debugging purposes.

Here are my simple code:

**main.py**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Get current timestamp
  current_time: str = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')

  # Initialize logging config
  logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    filename=f'./log/bot_{current_time}.log'
    )

  logging.info('Start of program.')
  execute()
  logging.info('End of program.')
```

**executes.py**

```
'''
  Here list of order of actions to be executed that has been defined from actions.py file.
'''

from actions import open_firefox, open_new_tab

def execute():
  """
    This is main program.
  """
  open_firefox()
  open_new_tab()
```

**actions.py**:

```
'''
 Here is list of actions defined that wrapped in functions to be used in executes.py file.
'''

from time import sleep
import logging
import pyautogui as pag

def open_firefox():
  """
    Open Firefox browser.
  """
  logging.info('Open Firefox browser.')
  firefox_icon_location = pag.locateCenterOnScreen('./asset/firefox.png', confidence=0.75)
  pag.moveTo(firefox_icon_location, duration=1)
  sleep(1)
  pag.leftClick()
  sleep(1)
  logging.info('Firefox browser has been opened.')

def open_new_tab():
  """
    Open new tab.
  """
  pag.hotkey('ctrl', 't')
  sleep(1)
```

Comment: wrap everything with a tkinter application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your existing scripts with a simple `tkinter` application, and add two buttons and a text widget there to view the logger info. Here's a basic example wrapped into one script:

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep
import logging
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import pyautogui as pag


def open_firefox():
    """Open Firefox browser."""
    logging.info('Open Firefox browser.')
    try:
        firefox_icon_location = pag.locateCenterOnScreen('./asset/firefox.png', confidence=0.75)
        if firefox_icon_location is not None:
            pag.moveTo(firefox_icon_location, duration=1)
            sleep(1)
            pag.leftClick()
            sleep(1)
            logging.info('Firefox browser has been opened.')
        else:
            logging.error('Firefox icon not found on screen.')
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error opening Firefox: {e}")

def open_new_tab():
    """Open new tab."""
    try:
        pag.hotkey('ctrl', 't')
        sleep(1)
        logging.info('New tab opened.')
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error opening new tab: {e}")


class TextHandler(logging.Handler):
    """ Custom logging handler sending logs to a Tkinter Text widget. """
    def __init__(self, text_widget):
        super().__init__()
        self.text_widget = text_widget

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        self.text_widget.configure(state='normal')
        self.text_widget.insert(tk.END, msg + '\n')
        self.text_widget.configure(state='disabled')
        # Scroll to the bottom
        self.text_widget.yview(tk.END)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Set up Tkinter window
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Firefox Control")
    root.geometry("400x400")

    # Create ScrolledText widget for logs
    log_widget = ScrolledText(root, state='disabled')
    log_widget.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    # Set up custom logging handler
    text_handler = TextHandler(log_widget)
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.addHandler(text_handler)
    
    logging.info('Start of program.')
    
    # Buttons
    button_firefox = tk.Button(root, text="Open Firefox", command=open_firefox)
    button_firefox.pack(pady=10)

    button_new_tab = tk.Button(root, text="Open New Tab", command=open_new_tab)
    button_new_tab.pack(pady=10)

    # Start the Tkinter event loop
    root.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

Check out `tkinter` documentation to learn more: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html